# Hiding implementation files in a package

Tags: python, dynamic, module, package

I have a module called `spellnum`. It can be used as a command-line utility (it has the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block) or it can be imported like a standard Python module.

The module defines a class named `Speller` which looks like this:

```
class Speller(object):
    def __init__(self, lang="en"):
        module = __import__("spelling_" + lang)
        # use module's contents...
```

As you can see, the class constructor loads other modules at runtime. Those modules (`spelling_en.py`, `spelling_es.py`, etc.) are located in the same directory as the `spellnum.py` itself.

Besides `spellnum.py`, there are other files with utility functions and classes. I'd like to hide those files since I don't want to expose them to the user and since it's a bad idea to pollute the Python's lib directory with random files. The only way to achieve this that I know of is to create a package.

---

I've come up with this layout for the project (inspired by this great [tutorial](http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/)):

```
spellnum/                # project root
    spellnum/            # package root
        __init__.py
        spellnum.py
        spelling_en.py
        spelling_es.py
        squash.py
        # ... some other private files
    test/
        test_spellnum.py
    example.py
```

The file `__init__.py` contains a single line:

```
from spellnum import Speller
```

Given this new layout, the code for dynamic module loading had to be changed:

```
class Speller(object):
    def __init__(self, lang="en"):
        spelling_mod = "spelling_" + lang
        package = __import__("spellnum", fromlist=[spelling_mod])
        module = getattr(package, spelling_mod)
        # use module as usual
```

So, with this project layout a can do the following:

1. Successfully `import spellnum` inside `example.py` and use it like a simple module:

   ```
   # an excerpt from the example.py file
   import spellnum

   speller = spellnum.Speller(es)
   # ...
   ```
2. `import spellnum` in the tests and run those tests from the project root like this:

   ```
   $ PYTHONPATH="`pwd`:$PYTHONPATH" python test/test_spellnum.py
   ```

#### The problem

I cannot execute `spellnum.py` directly with the new layout. When I try to, it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "spellnum/spellnum.py", line 23, in __init__
    module = getattr(package, spelling_mod)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spelling_en'
```

#### The question

What's the best way to organize all of the files required by my module to work so that users are able to use the module both from command line and from their Python code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about keeping `spellnum.py`?

```
spellnum.py
spelling/
  __init__.py
  en.py
  es.py
```

Comment: Thanks. I've chosen your approach and modified it slightly. Rather than having the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block inside `spellnum.py`, I've extracted it into a separate script. This makes it clear that `spellnum` is a module for use in Python code. The command-line script is only provided for convenience.

Comment: I have the same problem, but in adition to en.py and es.py, I have some utils modules. In en.py I import some functions from utils.
I can install my package properly but when I import it it says  'no module named spelling.utils'
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I [published it as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224965/hide-implementation-modules-and-submodules-in-package) since it is slightly different

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the package is called the same as the python-file you want to execute, thus importing

```
from spellnum import spellnum_en
```

will try to import from the file instead of the package. You could fiddle around with relative imports, but I don't know how to make them work with `__import__`, so I'd suggest the following:

```
def __init__(self, lang="en"):
    mod = "spellnum_" + lang
    module = None
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        module = __import__(mod)
    else:
        package = getattr(__import__("spellnum", fromlist=[mod]), mod)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works this way. However, I've decided to go a different way and extract the `main` part into a separate script.