# Hide implementation modules and submodules in package

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, pip, package

I want to package my code to expose only the main functions. My directory is like this:

```
./
  setup.py
  my_module/
    __init__.py
    public_functions.py
    internal_modules/
      __init__.py
      A.py
      B.py
      other_modules.py/
        __init__.py
        C.py
```

In `public_functions` I do import some operations from `internal_modules.A` but NOT from `internal_modules.B`, and both `A.py` and `B.py` uses some functions from `C.py`.

My `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_module',
      version='0.1',
      description='my_awesome_module',
      author='Me',
      author_email='example@mail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['my_module'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I want to install it with pip, but I want not to let any of my `internal_modules` visible from my package once it is installed.

I could install it properly but when I do

```
from my_module import public_module
```

it throws `ImportError: no module named internal_modules.A` in `public_module.py`'s first line.

I know I can fix it if I add `my_module.internal_modules` to my `setup.py` declaration as another package, but this will let my internal_modules public with `A.py` and `B.py` visible from installed package.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769991/hiding-implementation-files-in-a-package) but it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the internals of the module from an import by underscoring the module name:

_yourmodulenamegoeshere.

E:
You can also define `__all__` in the package's `__init__` - only the module names from `__all__` will be imported via import *.

Comment: I don't know how `__all__` in the package's `__init__` works. Can you give me an example?

By the way, underscoring `_internal_modules` didn't work. same error as before (`my_module._internal_modules`)

Comment: `__all__ = ['module1', 'module2']` will only import modules 1 & 2 if you do `from package import *`. You still could access the guts of the package directly if you wanted. _underscored modules should not be imported by default if you did `import package`, but likewise - a dedicated user can still access them.